# How do I parse three values from a string in C using sscanf when one is in double quotes?

Tags: c, parsing, scanf, fgets

I'm attempting to parse three strings from a larger string, but only the first two values are being parsed. Is there something wrong with my format string used by sscanf?

I've already tried using "%s %[^\n\t\^]s %s\n" as the format string, and it works for the first two values, but the third one remains blank.

```
printf(">> ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(input, MAX_STR, stdin);
sscanf(input, "%s %[^\t\n]s\n", command, value);

/* parse it differently if the command is average*/
if(!strcmp(command, "average")) {
  /* clear the values */
  strcpy(command, "");
  strcpy(reference, "");
  strcpy(value, "");

  /* re-parse the input */    
  sscanf(input, "%s \"%[^\t\n\"]s\" %[^\t\n]s\n", command, reference, value);
}

printf("command: %s reference: %s value: %s\n");
```

I'm expecting that if I type in say... average "cody" 500, that the print statement at the end would print

command: average reference: cody value: 500

but instead it prints

command: average reference: cody value:

for some reason the value string is cut off when parsing.

Comment: fwiw `strcpy(command, "");` is equivalent to `command[0]='\0';` which is probably more efficient.

Comment: Is this your real code? `printf("command: %s reference: %s value: %s\n");` this should throw an warning and not print what you say it prints

Comment: As @xing, you can have `%s` or `%[]` but `%[]s` is a hybrid unless you want to match an `'s'` from the input.

Comment: When you reparse, this: `\"%[^\t\n\"]s\"` should probably be this, instead: `\"%[^\"]\"`.  That is, in addition to dropping the `s`, you probably want to scan everything up to the next quotation mark, even whitespace.

Comment: I know your instructor and your textbooks make it seem like `scanf` is *the* function for input, but it's not.  If you're doing anything but "toy" input processing, `scanf` is usually inadequate for the job.  If you want to learn to do how to do input processing in C properly, your first step is going to have to be, sadly, to abandon `scanf` entirely.  (Me, I've been programming in C for 40 years, and I have virtually never used `scanf`.) `sscanf` is a little better, but not much.

Comment: @SteveSummit Knock down any windmills lately?

Comment: @Barmar No, but I do like this horse...

Comment: @SteveSummit OP's post does not include `scanf()` of your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550779/how-do-i-parse-three-values-from-a-string-in-c-using-sscanf-when-one-is-in-doubl/56552985#comment99683788_56550779).  It does use `fgets()` - good first step.

Comment: @SteveSummit So if not sscanf, what should I parse with then?

Comment: @xing ty, that solved my problem. 

also thanks for the tip on clearing the strings, Eugene.

Comment: @ZackaryF See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56569178/learning-inputs-in-c-opinion/56571542#56571542).

Answer (score 2):

If the input string is of the form ...

```
command "reference" value
```

... where `command` and `value` have no white-spaces, code can use:

```
char command[100], reference[100],  value[100];
int n = 0;
sscanf(input, "%99s \"%99[^\"]\" %99s %n", command, reference,  value, &n);
if (n > 0 && input[n] == 0) {
  // success
  printf("command: '%s' reference: '%s' value: '%s'\n", command, reference,  value);
}
```

A scan that succeeds will set the value of `n` and `input[n]` will be the *null character*.

---

It is often easier to follow parsing by breaking up the format

```
#define FMT_CMD "%99s"
#define FMT_REF " \"%99[^\"]\""
#define FMT_VAL "%99s"
sscanf(input, FMT_CMD FMT_REF FMT_VAL " %n", 
    command, reference,  value, &n);
```

---

With `sscanf(input, "%s %[^\t\n]s\n", command, value);` there is no width limit for `command, value` risking buffer overrun.  the final `'s'` in the format has no use.  Format's trailing `'\n'` also has no use.